# Why is my MariaDB import only importing some of the rows of data?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mariadb-10.4

I have a 12 GB .sql file that I got from our production server via `mysqldump`. Our production server and I are both using MariaDB 10.4 (I recently upgraded from MariaDB 5.5).

My coworkers (using MariaDB 10.1) are able to import the .sql file just fine. When I try to import, it *appears* to work, but on many of the tables (maybe only larger tables?) it is only importing a small percentage of the total rows. For example, on one table that is 1.5 million rows, my database only has 2,000 rows after the import is "complete".

I'm using `mysql -u [user] -p [db_name] < /path/to/datadump.sql` to import the data.

There are no errors in the errors log (`/var/log/mysqld.log`).

The environment is CentOS 6.10 running on a Vagrant box on MacOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysql_upgrade` seems to have done the trick. I tried many other things, including reinstalling MariaDB 10.4, setting `/etc/my.cnf` to default settings. The only thing that worked for me was `mysql_upgrade`.